# -[NSURL objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e1d6d0 ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest, sigabrt

I'm formatting an ASIHTTPRequest to send array data to a server. I have an array for keys (propertyKeys) and an array for the information (propertyValues) and have created a loop to set the post and key values as such.

```
for(int i = 0;i<13;i++){
    [request setPostValue:[propertyValues objectAtIndex:i] forKey:[propertyKeys objectAtIndex:i]];  
}
```

I am getting the following error, however:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e1d6d0'
```

I tried to look up the documentation for AHIHTTPRequest but the site seems to be down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that error happening within the code that you posted, or elsewhere? Running the app in debug mode (Cmd-Y) will let you follow the stack trace up to see exactly where a crash happened.

That said, if the crash is happening within what you posted, it probably means that either `propertyKeys` or `propertyValues` has been deallocated and that its pointer is now garbage. Make sure they aren’t getting released or autoreleased by the time you get to that part of your program.

Comment: so instead of defining them via something like NSArray propertyValues = [NSArray withObjects...] I should init it, or do I just need to call retain right after assigning variables to it?

Comment: crap nevermind, you were right. Originally I had combined them into an NSDictionary and then released the arrays. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

You have accidentally assign an `NSURL` rather than an `NSArray` to either `properyValues` or `propertyKeys`. Check what they are in the debugger at this point.

In many cases, the compiler will have thrown a warning when you did this. Make sure your code has no warnings. In Objective-C, warnings are almost always errors, and should never be ignored.